# Stream closes after first read on some XP machines

Tags: c#, caching, stream

I've got a desktop application which downloads some dlls from a web server, wich then loads them with `Assembly.Load`. On one XP machine, BadImageFormatExceptions were being thrown the second time I ran the application. On other Win 7 and XP machines, it worked fine.

It appears that only the first 65536 bytes of the dll were being returned, and that this only happened when the downloaded dll had been cached.

What could cause the truncation?

Here's how I reproduced the problem. First, download the file, adding it to the cache:

```
client = new WebClient();
client.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.Reload);
data = client.DownloadData(url);
Console.WriteLine("Got " + data.Length);
```

This works, in this case printing "Got 159744".

Normally I would use `RequestCacheLevel.Deafult`, but to reliably re-produce the problem I read only from the cache for the second request:

```
client = new WebClient();
client.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.CacheOnly);
data = client.DownloadData(url);
Console.WriteLine("Got " + data.Length);
```

On most machines, this outputs "Got 159744", however on the breaking XP machine, this outputs, "Got 65536". Looking at the source code for `WebClient`, it uses a buffer size of 65536 bytes. Suspecting a problem with `WebClient`, I reproduced the problem directly using a `WebRequest`:

```
request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.CacheOnly);
responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
var buffer = new byte[16384];
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    int read;
    while ((read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Read... " + read + " bytes");
        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    data = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
Console.WriteLine("Got " + data.Length);
```

In this case, only one "Read..." line is output, and only 16384 bytes are read. No end of stream exception is thrown, and the bytes which I do get look good.

It seems like a problem with the response stream ending too soon, but what could be causing that?

Comment: There are about 10 .NET assemblies I'm trying to download, totaling about 11MB. The one I've been testing against is a 156KB dll. I've got a x86 test XP machine too, where it works. I'm trying to work out what could cause the difference between the machines, any other ideas?

Comment: Do you dispose WebClient? and responseStream?

Comment: No, I wasn't disposing the WebClient. I am now, but the results are the same unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried doing the download with some other program on that machine? If that works, then you can suspect your program (or the WebClient). If it doesn't work, then you have a problem with your network stack, or perhaps with the hardware.

Comment: The machine is broken.  Throw it away, this isn't worth your time.

Comment: What version of the framework are you using? The first thing I would suspect is that the working machines have some update applied that the others don't.

Answer (score 0):

There is a platform target inconsistency between your assemblies.

Most likely a mixture of "AnyCPU" and "x86" assemblies that would work fine on a 32bit CLR, not so on 64bit CLR (as AnyCPU is loaded as 64bit which breaks dependencies on x86 assemblies).

Make sure all your assemblies have a consistent target - All AnyCPU or all x86.

You could also try this

```
 corflags myassembly.exe /32bit+
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Why do you think that it is a problem with platform target? If client.DownloadData doesn't return an array with the correct length, surely the platform target doesn't matter? Or could a platform target inconsistency somehow cause the cache to not work?